# HTML5 video, how to detect when there is no audio track?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a chrome app and I'd like to have custom controls for the video playback but I'm having some difficulties with the mute button. Most of the videos that will be played in the app are silent so I'd like to be able to disable the button when there is no audio track just like chrome does with the default controls.

Tried using the volume value but it returns "1" even though there's no audio track. Checking if the video is muted didn't work either.

Here's a [snippet](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aoyrv).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible.  Plus, there are several videos that have an audio track but it remains silent the whole time.

Comment: never say never: you can feed the video's audio into a webAudio API manipulation to verify non-silence. only works in chrome and maybe FF, and i don't know how to do it, but it can be done...

Comment: @dandavis: That should work in [Chrome, FF and Safari](http://caniuse.com/audio-api).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At some point, browsers might start implementing the [audioTracks property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks). For now, you can use `webkitAudioDecodedByteCount` for webkit, and `mozHasAudio` for firefox.

```
document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("loadeddata", function() {
  if (typeof this.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount !== "undefined") {
    // non-zero if video has audio track
    if (this.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount > 0)
      console.log("video has audio");
    else
      console.log("video doesn't have audio");
  }
  else if (typeof this.mozHasAudio !== "undefined") {
    // true if video has audio track
    if (this.mozHasAudio)
      console.log("video has audio");
    else
      console.log("video doesn't have audio");
  }
  else
    console.log("can't tell if video has audio");
});
```

Comment: This always return 0 for audios, do you know how to check if audio has sound?

Comment: *Info:* 2022. - and still not implemented.

Answer (score 20):

Shorter function based on upuoth's answer and extended to support IE10+

```
function hasAudio (video) {
    return video.mozHasAudio ||
    Boolean(video.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount) ||
    Boolean(video.audioTracks && video.audioTracks.length);
}
```

Usage:

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');
if(hasAudio(video)) {
    console.log("video has audio");
} else{
    console.log("video doesn't have audio");
}
```

Comment: Guys don't forget about `addEventListener("loadeddata")` on video element.

Comment: I logged `hasAudio(video)` inside event listeners on my video element for both `loadeddata` and `loadedmetadata`, and in my case `loadedmetadata`'s logged `false` while `loadeddata`'s logged `true`.

Comment: The problem with this code is that `webkitAudioDecodedByteCount` isn't a reliable way to detect whether audio exists or not. If `webkitAudioDecodedByteCount` is greater than 0, great, your video definitely has audio. But if it's 0, all that means is that no audio data has been decoded *yet*. You'll have to wait a little while and check it again, and again, and again, until it either becomes non-zero or you're reasonably sure that there is indeed no audio.

Comment: That applies to every check out here: _some_ data needs to be loaded, that's why the first comment here suggest using this _after_ `loadeddata`, or maybe even later.

Comment: @fregante The difference is that the data not only has to be *loaded*, it also has to be *decoded*. And there's no event for that. So no matter if you call it in `loadedmetadata` or `loadeddata`, the result is not reliable. 99% of the time, getting 0 from `webkitAudioDecodedByteCount` means you should try again later.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason [@fregante's `hasAudio` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31022391/11950764) stopped working in Chrome at some point - even after waiting for the "loadeddata" and "loadedmetadata" events, and even the "canplaythrough" event. It may have something to do with the video format I'm using (webm). In any case, I solved it by playing the video for a short amount of time:

```js
// after waiting for the "canplaythrough" event:
hasAudio(video); // false
video.play();
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
video.pause();
hasAudio(video); // true
```

Comment: Chrome is weird like that. It doesn't allow certain events to work unless the user interacts with the page, it doesn't allow checking for audio unless the video has played for a duration, and more weirdness. You'd think that'd make it decent at privacy, but it just means normal actions require workarounds to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to check whether a video file has audio or not, one of which is to use `mozHasAudio`, `video.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount` and `video.audioTracks?.length` properties of video, clean and simple...

```
const video = component.node.querySelector("video");
video.onloadeddata = function() {
    if ((typeof video.mozHasAudio !== "undefined" && video.mozHasAudio) ||
        (typeof video.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount !== "undefined" && video.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount > 0) ||
        Boolean(video.audioTracks?.length)) {
        console.log("This video has audio tracks.");
    } else {
        console.log("This video has no audio tracks.");
    }            
};
```