# JavaScript detect if video has sound from a response

Tags: javascript, request, fetch

I am making a static html page that is fetches for somewhere between six and thirty files with `fetch`. I am going to implement code that sorts the files by content type later, but what is important to me right now is detect if the files that are videos have sound or not. I don't know how to do this. For speed purposes, I only fetch the responses HEAD. Here is what I have so far:

```
//links is an array of values that are the urls to the videos
links.forEach(function(item, index) {
    var requestplace = new Request(item);
    fetch(requestplace, {method: 'HEAD'}).then(function(response) {
        if (response.ok) {
            var ctype = response.headers.get("Content-Type")
            console.log(`Link #${index + 1}: Url:${item} Content-Type: ${ctype}`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Link #${index + 1}: Url:${item} FAILED!`);
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to know if anyone knows how to detect if the response video has sound tracks included with it.
**EDIT:**
I would prefer if the files were requested with `HEAD` because it seems that it is the quickest way possible, but it is preferable not necessary.

Comment: You can't make just a `HEAD` request.  You need to actually fetch the media data, at least partially, to determine what streams are in the container.

Comment: @Brad Do you mind making an example without the `HEAD` request?

Comment: How would you be able to tell this without parsing the entire video file? An hour-long video may be completely silent for the first 59 minutes, and have sound only for the last minute.

Comment: @kmoser, I am not sure that you understand the situation. I am trying to detect if there is an audio track included in the video file.

Comment: @myjobistobehappy Ok, having an audio track is not the same as "having sound" so thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @kmoser It is not a stream, so it doesn't really help.

Comment: @myjobistobehappy So what kind of file is it?

Comment: @kmoser It is going to mp4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604696/use-javascript-to-detect-if-an-mp4-video-has-a-sound-track