# How to check audio in Video file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

how to check if there exists an audio track when a video file is loading/playing in HTML5 video player?

Comment: There is no way to do this client-side.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270048/html5-video-how-to-detect-when-there-is-no-audio-track

Answer (score 1):

Since the video tag is an `HTMLMediaElement` you could try to use the `audioTracks` property and see if it returns anything. But it's not widely supported ( http://caniuse.com/#search=audiotracks )

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And then

```
console.log( $("video").audioTracks );
```

More info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

Comment: I saw html player adjusts its audio control based on the audio track in the file. if there is no audio signal then audio control is disabled. how player does that?

Comment: If the browser (the handler of that html player) is using that `audioTracks` property, it disables the the audio control when there is no audio track on that element. 
If your browser doesn't support that, I sincerely don't know. Maybe you should try to make a different workaround approach, like the one the other answer is proposing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way on the client side.

Pretty far fetched, you might try to visualize the audio signal of the video and see if there is any activity.

Here is an approach to this:
http://www.patrick-wied.at/blog/how-to-create-audio-visualizations-with-javascript-html