# How can I load a video using selenium?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html5-video

I am trying to detect if a video on a webpage has an audio track but I cannot get selenium to load videos.

Here is roughly what I'm doing:

```
const webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser("firefox")
    .usingServer(myGridURL)
    .build();

const done = (result) => console.log(result);

driver.get(urlWithHTML5Video).then(() => {
    driver.executeAsyncScript(() => {
        const done = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
        const video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];

        video.addEventListener("loadeddata", function() {
            if (this.mozHasAudio > 0) {
                done("audio track detected");
            } else {
                done("audio track not detected");
            }
        }, false);

        video.load();

        setTimeout(() => {
            done("video did not load");
        }, 10000);
    });
}, [], done);
```

This always prints "video did not load", even when I check the status after waiting for several seconds the video `readyState` is always `0` and `mozHasAudio` is always `false`. I have also tried this in Chrome, while I am getting a `readState` value that indicates that the video has loaded, I cannot get a positive value for `webkitAudioDecodedByteCount` which should indicate that the video has an audio track (which it does).

This is what I tried on Chrome:

```
video.play().then(() =>
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(video.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount); // never reached
        video.pause();
    }, 100))
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(video.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount); // always 0
    console.log("video did not load"); // always reached
}, 10000);
```

I am using a shared selenium grid which should be accessing real (non-headless) versions of Firefox and Chrome. I am not exactly sure how these machines are set up so it is possible that I need to send in additional parameters to the driver to have video enabled but I haven't been able to determine if and what those are.

**EDIT**

Just to be sure, I took a screenshot:

[image: a video component showing "no video with supported format and mime type found"]

Comment: Have you tried using selenium to execute the javascript in this answer and then return a boolean? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31022391/26197

Comment: @Zugwalt, yes, I've tried all sorts of ways to get info from the video but it appears as though the browser won't support mp4 or any other video types