# How to check if a video source has audio in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, video, html5-video

I have a video player that has a video source loaded from a URL. I need to set it to mute all the time only IF it does not have any audio so that the user knows the video does not have any audio.

How can I do that?

Comment: I ended up using a solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270048/html5-video-how-to-detect-when-there-is-no-audio-track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been some time but I wanted to close it with my answer.
I referenced the solution here:
[HTML5 video, how to detect when there is no audio track?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270048/html5-video-how-to-detect-when-there-is-no-audio-track)

```
function hasAudio (video) {
    return video.mozHasAudio ||
    Boolean(video.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount) ||
    Boolean(video.audioTracks && video.audioTracks.length);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest testing for `audioTracks` property first, as it's supposed to be standard; then check for vendor prefixed (`mozHasAudio`, `webkitAudioDecodedByteCount`).

Comment: @TassoEvangelista Thanks for the suggestion. Iirc, the webkitAudioDecodedByte worked for me. mozHasAudio wasn't suitable as I had to get it working on Chrome + other browsers too.
I think audioTracks worked too but couldn't be sure as this was quite a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

Video tag has  a prop called [mute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-muted) that will mute the video.

Comment: Yes, I can mute but I need to check i the video really doesn't have any audio 1st. How do I do the check?

Comment: You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270048/html5-video-how-to-detect-when-there-is-no-audio-track)

Comment: I saw that one too. Looks like it's the most suitable solution I could find. Thanks